# Convention Badge - Should all ten posts have score of 2 or more?

Tags: discussion, badges

For Convention badge, should all posts have score of 2 or more, or should have 10 posts and one of them could have score of 2?

Comment: What is this "convention" badge ?

Comment: It's 10 posts, all having a score of 2 or more. That badge description seems pretty straightforward. How do you interpret the "score of 2 or more" to only apply to one post?

Comment: @BadWolf -Thanks, will check link.

Comment: @animuson - Was confused.. thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have ten (10) posts on meta having a score of 2 or better. All of your posts don't need to score 2 or better, just as long as 10 of them have a score of 2 or better.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, so all ten should have score of 2 or more.